# Segmentation when I encounter a 1 using recursion

Tags: c, arrays, recursion, 2d

I am supposed to use recursion to check all the neighbors, like the Moore's neighbor, and check the randomly generated array for all the 1's that are connected using the Moore's neighbor. My recursion code seem to work fine when it encounters a zero, but it gives me a segmentation fault when it encounters a one. I tried gdb and valgrind but it gave me this error.

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000400a34 in recursive (arr=0x6030b0, xcoord=-1, 
ycoord=0, row=6, 
    col=6) at as4.c:79
79          if(arr[xcoord][ycoord] == 1)
```

and when I type where in gdb()where: I get this

```
#0  0x0000000000400a34 in recursive (arr=0x6030b0, xcoord=-1, 
ycoord=0, row=6, 
col=6) at as4.c:79

#1  0x0000000000400a61 in recursive (arr=0x6030b0, xcoord=0, 
ycoord=0, row=6, 
col=6) at as4.c:83

#2  0x0000000000400975 in main (argc=3, argv=0x7fffffffdf48) at 
as4.c:56
```

So I am not sure if I am mallocing something wrong or if my recursion is just wrong. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int recursive(int **arr, int xcoord, int ycoord, int row, int col);//What are the arguments for the recursive function?

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int i;//counters
    int j;//counters
    int xcoord;//x coordinate input
    int ycoord;//y coordinate input

    //random number generator thing idk lol
    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));

    int row = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 0);//ROW from command line arguments (1st number)
    int col = strtol(argv[2], NULL, 0);//COL from command line arguments (2nd number)

    int *arrStorage = malloc(row * col * sizeof(int));//dynamically allocating memory for 2d array
    int **arr = malloc(row * sizeof(int));        //pointer to pointer to array or whatever

    //intializing array
    for (i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
            arr[i] = arrStorage + col * i;
    }

    //printing out 2d array
        for (i = 0; i <  row; i++)
    {
            for (j = 0; j < col; j++)
        {
            arr[i][j] = rand() % 2;
            printf("%d\t", arr[i][j]);
        }

        printf("\n");
    }

    printf(" ");

    //Exit the function when non number is entered
    //Otherwise continue
    while(1)
    {
        printf("Enter coordinate i,j (Non numeric to quit) \n");    

        if(1!=scanf("%d", &xcoord) || 1!=scanf("%d", &ycoord))
        {
            return 0;
        }

        printf("Blob size: %d\n", recursive(arr, xcoord, ycoord, row, col));
        printf("The total size it takes up is %d percent \n", recursive(arr, xcoord, ycoord, row, col)/(row*col));
    }

    for (i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        free(arr[i]);
    }
}

int recursive(int **arr, int xcoord, int ycoord, int row, int col)
{
    int blobsize = 0;

    //if coordinate is out of bounds or the user puts in too small or big coordinate return 0
    if(xcoord < 0 && ycoord < 0 && xcoord > row && ycoord > col)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    //recursively check all the neighbors
    else
    {
        if(arr[xcoord][ycoord] == 1)
        {
            blobsize = blobsize + 1;

            if(recursive(arr, xcoord - 1, ycoord, row, col))//Check up
            {
                if(arr[xcoord][ycoord] == 1)
                {
                    blobsize = blobsize + 1;
                }
                return 1;
            }

            if(recursive(arr, xcoord - 1, ycoord + 1, row, col))//Check right up
            {
                if(arr[xcoord][ycoord] == 1)
                {
                    blobsize = blobsize + 1;
                }
                return 1;
            }

            if(recursive(arr, xcoord, ycoord + 1, row, col))//Check right
            {
                if(arr[xcoord][ycoord] == 1)
                {
                    blobsize = blobsize + 1;
                }
                return 1;
            }

            if(recursive(arr, xcoord + 1, ycoord + 1, row, col))//Check bottom right
            {
                if(arr[xcoord][ycoord] == 1)
                {
                    blobsize = blobsize + 1;
                }
                return 1;
            }

            if(recursive(arr, xcoord + 1, ycoord, row, col))//Check bottom
            {
                if(arr[xcoord][ycoord] == 1)
                {
                    blobsize = blobsize + 1;
                }
                return 1;   
            }

            if(recursive(arr, xcoord + 1, ycoord-1, row, col))
            {
                if(arr[xcoord][ycoord] == 1)
                {
                    blobsize = blobsize + 1;
                }
                return 1;
            }

            if(recursive(arr, xcoord, ycoord-1, row, col))
            {
                if(arr[xcoord][ycoord] == 1)
                {
                    blobsize = blobsize + 1;
                }
                return 1;
            }

            if(recursive(arr, xcoord - 1, ycoord - 1, row, col))
            {
                if(arr[xcoord][ycoord] == 1)
                {
                    blobsize = blobsize + 1;
                }
                return 1;
            }       
        }
    }

    return blobsize;
}
```

And yeah I do have to use recursion to check all my neighbors and increment blobsize by 1 if I encounter a 1 at a certain position.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158131/discussion-on-question-by-anonymous-segmentation-when-i-encounter-a-1-using-recu).

Answer (score 0):

Your recursion never ends and the program fails because a stackoverflow. For example, for 6x6, it will check ...(4,4),(5,5),(4,4),(5,5)... calling `recursive` endlessly, blowing up the stack.

Also, `free` both pointers like

```
free(arrStorage)
free(arr)
```

since libc/kernel does not know how to `free(a[i])`

Answer (score 0):

A really nice way to do this (that is easy to optimize because you can build a queue instead of using recursion) is to use what is called the tricolor algorithm.

http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs2112/2012sp/lectures/lec24/lec24-12sp.html

Basically you:

1) mark all squares of the type you are searching white

2)start on a white square: 
- mark that square black
-mark all its neighbors (of the same type) grey and put them at the end of the queue

3) grab a grey square off the front of the queue:
-mark it black
-mark all of its white neighbors grey and put them at the end of the queue

do/ while there are squares on the queue.

count the black squares, this is your connected blob

Note: This creates a coloring with an invarient. After each iteration there  will never be a black square adjacent to a white square.
this algorithm runs in O(n)